# Heavy-tailed distribution with closed-form ML fit from data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, heavy-tailed

Which (if any) [heavy-tailed distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution) can we compute the maximum likelihood parameters of, given some data to fit the distribution to?

Comment: Why are you looking for a heavy-tailed distribution? Perhaps some context would help getting an answer. Your question might be a bit too broad as it stands now.

Comment: "Mixing" distributions are useful - you can use the EM algorithm for these to find MLEs.  Examples include negative binomial (poisson-gamma), student (normal-inverse gamma), beta prime (gamma-gamma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a characterization of all such would probably be a very broad question indeed.

However, it's possible to give a strategy to generate a very broad range of examples.

So here's a strategy to obtain *closed form* estimators for a large variety of heavy-tailed distributions.

Note the [invariance to a broad class of transformations of data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Functional_invariance) (see the second half of that section, not the first part on transformation of the parameter).

So this should allow you to generate as many as you like -

(1) pick some distribution with a nice closed-form MLE for some parameter

(2) pick some nice transformation of the variable (one that retains the invariance to transformations of data) which transforms a random variable with a distribution in (1) to one in the class of heavy-tailed distributions (by whichever definition of heavy-tailedness you like). Exponentiation (or repeated exponentiation, $\exp(\exp(...(x)))$) and inversion are examples of transformations that may sometimes take you to nice heavy-tailed distributions.

(3) voila!

So consider two obvious examples of [heavy-tailed distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution#Common_heavy-tailed_distributions) with nice closed form for some parameter or parameters -

1. The shape parameter (tail index) of a Pareto distribution with lower limit $x_m=1$ (which will clearly be closed form because it corresponds to the rate parameter of an exponential - and indeed it [is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Parameter_estimation) closed form $\widehat \alpha = \frac{n}{\sum _i \ln x_i}$).
2. Both parameters for a lognormal distribution, since the MLEs for the corresponding normal are closed form.